# Regarding X++ query

Tags: x++

How i convert below SQL query into X++ code.I uses a empltable and join this table with HRPPARTYPOSITIONTABLERELAT2226,and in  HRPPARTYPOSITIONTABLERELAT2226
used self join..

```
enter code here

 select e.EMPLID,
 LastDate.TITLE,
 e.DIMENSION3_,
 LastDate.ORGANIZATIONUNITID,
 LastDate.DESCRIPTION,
 e.JOINDATE,
 e.CITEXITDATE,
 LastDate.VALIDTODATETIME
from EMPLTABLE e, 
(select *
from HRPPARTYPOSITIONTABLERELAT2226 bc1
where VALIDTODATETIME = (
    Select MAX(VALIDTODATETIME) 
    from HRPPARTYPOSITIONTABLERELAT2226 bc2
    where bc2.REFERENCE= bc1.REFERENCE)) LastDate 
where e.EMPLID = LastDate.REFERENCE and EMPLSTATUS != 1 and            LastDate.DATAAREAID = 'new'
```

Comment: Have you tried anything and what are the issues you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

From the table names it seems you are on version AX 2009 or earlier. And the requirement behind your SQL query seems to be to show some employee data along with some additional data from the last position they held.

Unfortunately as far as I know there is no way like in SQL to do this in one query. You need at least two. One way to do it is to first determine all the last positions held by employees by doing an aggregated query on the `HRPPartyPositionTableRelationship` table. From these results you can then select the corresponding `EmplTable` and full `HRPPartyPositionTableRelationship` records.

This could look like the following code. Note that this is not an exact representation of your query, but I'm sure you can add the missing field lists and criteria on your own.

```cs
EmplTable emplTable;
HRPPartyPositionTableRelationship hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship;
HRPPartyPositionTableRelationship hrpPartyPositionTableRelationshipLatest;
;

while select Reference, maxof(ValidToDateTime) from hrpPartyPositionTableRelationshipLatest
    group by Reference
    where hrpPartyPositionTableRelationshipLatest.HRMReferenceType == HRMVirtualNetworkReferenceType::Employee
{

    select emplTable where emplTable.EmplId == hrpPartyPositionTableRelationshipLatest.Reference
        join hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship where hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.HRMReferenceType == HRMVirtualNetworkReferenceType::Employee
                                                  && hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.Reference        == emplTable.EmplId
                                                  && hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.ValidToDateTime  == hrpPartyPositionTableRelationshipLatest.ValidToDateTime;

    info(strFmt('%1, %2, %3, %4', emplTable.EmplId, hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.Title, hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.Description, hrpPartyPositionTableRelationship.ValidToDateTime));
}
```